# get form element from dialog box using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, salesforce

I am using jQuery on a standard salesforce page. I can only place my jQuery script in the main page. When I click on an inline edit element, a dialog box opens up and this dialog  box has a few input fields. I want to know how to access the input fields in the dialog box from the jQuery which is placed in the Main page.

Please help!!

Regards
Sameer

Comment: is the dialog box in the main page?  if its just a dialog , it should still be part of the same HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link type="text/css" href="js/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/ui.dialog.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/ui.resizable.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/ui.draggable.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" href="js/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var cancel = function() {
            $("#myDialog").dialog("close");
        }
        var getResponse = function(){
          var answer;
          $("input").each(function(){
            (this.checked == true) ? answer = $(this).val() : null;
          });
          $("<p>").text(answer).insertAfter($("#poll"));
          $("#myDialog").dialog("close");
        }
        var dialogOpts = {
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            "Done": getResponse,
            "Cancel": cancel
          },
          autoOpen: false
        };
        $("#myDialog").dialog(dialogOpts);
        $("#poll").click(function() {
          $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
        });  
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="poll">Poll</button>
    <div id="myDialog" class="flora" title="This is the title">
      <p>Question?</p>
      <label for="yes">Yes!</label><input type="radio" id="yes" value="yes" name="question"><br>
      <label for="no">No!</label><input type="radio" id="no" value="no" name="question">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `(this.checked == true) ? answer = $(this).val() : null;` should just be `answer = this.value`. Why set `answer` to `null` then return it as text?

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial might help you to start from somewhere: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b16V25eNyJY&feature=relmfu

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the code we could exactly show you.
You can access it by, For instance specifying it's id:

```
$("#the_id_element")
```